# XML - Understanding difficulties parsing XML using JDOM

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jdom

I got this particular XML file, it looks like this:

```
<App01_Storage Type="VOLATILE" Size="200000" Speed="15" LatencyMaxWrite="1" LatencyMaxRead="2" Endurance="12" WorkloadPeak="15" />
```

In my program I iterate through all children of the root node. My intention is to get all children with their Attributes + values. One child looks like the code above.

```
System.out.println(node.getName());
System.out.println(node.getAttributes());
```

The System.Out-Method gives me this Output:
    App01_Storage
[[Attribute: Type="VOLATILE"], [Attribute: Size="200000"], [Attribute: Speed="15"], [Attribute: LatencyMaxWrite="1"], [Attribute: LatencyMaxRead="2"], [Attribute: Endurance="12"], [Attribute: WorkloadPeak="15"]]

I guess I am on the right way. According to my understanding one attribute should look like that: Attribute.Name = Attribute.Value

I want to save the attributes plus values in a different class and dont know how I exactly can get the values plus the name separetaly. The Output I get right now is a List with each entry Attributename = Attributevalue, like one single String. With this single String i cannot work.

Am I seeing something wrong? Hopefully I could explain myself. Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node.getAttributes()` gives you a list of attributes which you can iterate over again. The ouput you see is just the result of the lists `toString()` methode which is called when you hand it over to `System.out.println()`.

Do something like this:

```
for(Attribute attribute : node.getAttributes()) {
    String attributeName = attribute.getName();
    String value = attribute.getValue();
}
```

There are also other get-methods that already return a certain type (like `getIntValue()`). Look at the [`Attribute` documentation](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Attribute.html)